# SP_HELPTEXT in Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am using SSIS to connect to ORACLE database and i want to view TEXT for some view. I followed this [link](http://marikoonnet.blogspot.com/2010/03/sphelptext-in-oracle.html) but its giving me invalid syntax error.

```
SET LINESIZE 132
SET LONG 4000
SELECT TEXT FROM ALL_SOURCE WHERE NAME = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

Please suggest any other alternative.

**Update:**

Meanwhile i have checked for another option

```
select TEXT from ALL_VIEWS where view_name = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

This is getting sucessfully parsed but ORA -24374 define not done before error is coming

Comment: What invalid syntax error is it giving? I am able to run those statements without any problem

Comment: I am using SSIS ORACLE Connector i dont have any studio/SQL plus to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked finally in SQL PLUS. Not sure why this is not working with SSIS adapter.

```
select TEXT from ALL_VIEWS where view_name = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can try the dbms_metadata package:

For a view:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME')
from dual;
```

You are using "procedure name" as the parameter so I'm not sure if you are actually trying to get the source for a stored procedure. In that case you need something like this:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE', 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME')
from dual;
```

Comment: @PratikGupta: this all seems a problem of that "SSIS" tool (whatever that is). Those are sure valid Oracle queries.

Comment: I agree,since its a adapter (by microsoft) it might be causing problem in parsing oracle query.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this approach but had no success because it was not searching into all schemas I have on my database.

```sql
select TEXT from ALL_VIEWS where view_name = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'
```

So I found this another one that could help me with this!

```sql
select text
from dba_source
where NAME='YOUR_SP_NAME'
```